# How to Plot Multiple Plots Using for Loop for Each Column in My Data-Frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know how can I iterate through each column and plot a separate box plot for the values of each column using for loop in python.

[image: Kaggle Dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a list of your columns (say a list of list), you can use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = ...
#data = [column1, column2, column3]
for elem in data:
    plt.plot(elem)
    plt.show()
```

This code will create on plot for each column and will create a new one when you close the current.

I guess you don't want to plot everything on the same graph but you could do it by unindenting once the last line of my example `plt.show()`.